# geom_label_repel text justification and alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Is there a possible work-around to left-justify the text label created by `geom_label_repel` (or `geom_text_repel`) in the example below where all text are placed with positive `nudge_x` value and y-only adjusted position in `direction` parameter?  Currently, the default behavior is to center-align the text:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg, colour=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller=label_both) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.5)) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)), 
               size=3, segment.size=0.25, nudge_x=0.5, direction="y")
```

[image]

I am looking to emulate the left-justification that is possible in `geom_label` (or `geom_text`) by setting `hjust=0` as seen in example below, while being able to automatically repel labels in the y direction:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg, colour=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller=label_both) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.5)) + 
  geom_label(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)), size=3, nudge_x=0.2, hjust=0)
```

[image]

Edited: As a hack, would it be possible to build hjust (and vjust) into ggrepel?

Comment: I think it might be possible to support `hjust` and `vjust` in ggrepel. If someone wants to try, I'd be happy to review a pull request on github: https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 4 years since OP posted this question, `hjust=` seems to have been added to the `ggrepel` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg, colour=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller=label_both) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 1.5)) + 
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label=rownames(mtcars)), hjust=0,
    size=3, segment.size=0.25, nudge_x=0.5, direction="y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hoorah! Exactly what I was looking for!